# Jacobian matrix X going from x to the y coordinate system

Tags: matrix, jacobian

In Christoper Bishop's book Pattern Recognition and Machine learning, they use Jacobian to convert covariance matrix x to y.

[image]

However, according to definitions on Wikipedia, the definition of Jacobian matrix is [image]

Thus I wonder if there is a problem. Why xi is as the numerator while yi is the denominator?  I think for x coordinate system to the y coordinate system , It should be (partial derivitave of yi)/(partial derivative of xi) as Jacobian matrix.

Notice that the text specifically stressed' in going from x to y coordinate system' therefore the Jacobian matrix, in my opinion, should be formed as y as the nominator and x as the denominator, otherwise it should be going from y to x coordinate system.

Can someone please tell me why is that? Thank you!

Comment: (1) Your first equation has a typographical error (it is missing a "$j$" in the fraction).  (2) Otherwise, the *only* difference between the two lines is the choice of letters.  Absent an explanation of what those letters mean, we have to presume the two lines are equivalent mathematical expressions.